# Navigation bar moves for no apparent reason

Tags: html, css, navigation, navigationcontroller

I was playing around with a website mostly for my learning purposes and on just one of my pages the navigation bar is shifted about 5 pixels to the left than all the other pages. I see no reason why it shouldn't be exactly the same as the others. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the only page long enough to have a vertical scroll bar, which takes up some space on the right side of the screen.

If it bothers you, you can force all your pages to have some vertical scroll by adding the following code to your css file:

```
html { height: 101%; }
```

This makes each page just slightly longer than the browser window, no matter what size it is!

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much, I'll do that.

Answer (score 7):

```
html{ overflow-y:scroll; }
```

is even better because it shows the scrollbar alyways without the 1px scrollway of the other suggested solution

Answer (score 3):

That page is longer than the others.  Since the page is centered, your browser is making room for the scrollbar along the right hand side, which is not present in the other pages.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! Thank you so much for your help. Is there a simple remedy?